# canvas basics, can't have access to the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, html5-canvas

I have an array, and wanna use that in my document.ready function to call a function, which is in an external JS file. But it doesn't work, and I really don't know why. I have no experience with javascript or canvas, could anyone please help me out with this simple problem?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var thisIsMyArray= {
            x : 200,
            y : 150,
            size : 50
        };

        anyfunction(thisIsMyArray.x, thisIsMyArray.y, thisIsMyArray.size);
    });
</script>
```

external JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


var anyfunction = function(x, y, size) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see any array...

Comment: What has this got to do with canvas? All the code here is fine, except that that is an object, not an array. You'll need to provide more code. I'm guessing the problem is the way you've included the external script

Comment: Are there any errors in the console (hit F12 in Chrome on Windows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't select the canvas proper.

You mix up jQuery and JavaScript..

## Your error

```
// var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; WRONG
var canvas = $("canvas")[0]; // Use this
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas"); // Or this
```

Also your array is an object, not an array ;)

## Full code

```
var canvas = $("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var anyfunction = function (x, y, size) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, size, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var myObject = {
        x: 30,
        y: 30,
        size: 30
    };

    anyfunction(myObject.x, myObject.y, myObject.size);
});
```

## Example

http://jsfiddle.net/fZBwK/